# How can I use Less in a Ruby on Rails 3.1 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, less, asset-pipeline

What is the easiest (is there an easy way?) to use [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) (in combination with [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29)/Scss) in the Ruby on Rails 3.1 assets pipeline?

I want to load a file like foo.css.less like I would do for bar.css.scss

I found some wonky solution that does not work for me (haven't tried a lot):
https://github.com/thisduck/ruby-less-js/issues/2

The idea would be to use Twitter Bootstrap in a clean way.

Answer (score 10):

If you only want to use Bootstrap, you can do it by including the 'less-rails' and 'less-rails-bootstrap' gems in your Gem file.

Then, you can @import bootstrap in your .css.less files:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap"
```

Alternatively, you can include each constituent file individually (excluding those you don't want):

```
// Reset
@import "twitter/bootstrap/reset";

// Core variables and mixins
@import "twitter/bootstrap/variables";

@import "twitter/bootstrap/mixins";

// Grid system and page structure
@import "twitter/bootstrap/scaffolding";

// Styled patterns and elements
@import "twitter/bootstrap/type";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/forms";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/tables";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/patterns";
```

If you don't want to use the less-rails-bootstrap gem for whatever reason, or you have non-bootstrap .less files that you want to include, you need to manually add your .less paths to the less-rails config.

Note that none of this extra work is necessary if your filenames end in .css.less as the asset-pipeline should handle that compilation for you (as long as you've included 'less-rails'). This procedure is only required if you want to refer to external .less files directly in your app's .css.less files.

The setup I use for bootstrap is to copy the *.less files to `vendor/assets/frameworks/twitter/bootstrap`. Keeping the files in `vendor/assets/stylesheets/...` caused me some issues, probably due to Ruby on Rails magic resolving my imports to the unprocessed .less files and not knowing what to do with them (this is only speculation on my part, I didn't look into it fully).

Once you've got the .less files in your project, you need to tell less-rails where to find them. Do that by putting the following in your `application.rb`.

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  config.less.paths << File.join(Rails.root,'vendor','frameworks')
  # Should be set to true in production.
  config.less.compress = false
end
```

You can them import them in .css.less files by using:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/reset"
@import "twitter/bootstrap/variables"
...
```

Comment: I used your second approach and it absolutely works! Thank you @billmag

Answer (score 1):

The guy from [this blog post](http://metaskills.net/2011/09/26/less-is-more-using-twitter-bootstrap-in-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline/) created the [Less Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) gem.

It makes it easy to less in a Ruby on Rails 3.1 project.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this, but I haven't had a chance to test yet.

http://www.ciddennis.com/2011/09/getting-twitter-bootstrap-to-work-with-rails-31-asset-pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

See the discussion about different approaches in http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score -1):

Just put your `yourlessfile.less` file into `public/stylesheets`, and then in your view, include it with

```
stylesheet_link_tag "/stylesheets/yourlessfile.less", :rel => "stylesheet/less"
```

Don't forget include less.js in your view.

Comment: Yes sure, this is a clean and simple solution, but the less file does not go thru the assets pipeline. I want it to be processed by sprocket and compressed with the rest...

Comment: It's a nice answer to the question header but not the question details. It's handy for the people searching who see the header.