# Using Less in a Rails 3.1 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, less

I've just upgraded my application to the latest release of rails (3.1) and I'm wanting to integrate Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) into my application but it uses LESS and not SASS which is what Rails 3.1 uses by default.

How do I go about configuring Rails to use Less instead of Sass?

Comment: This is very similar to another question which is pretty well answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320582/how-to-use-less-in-a-rails-3-1-application

Comment: @billmag That question talks about using Less in combination with Sass rather than instead of.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As apneadiving points out, Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS.

To configure your Rails app to support LESS, you can add the gem to the assets group of your Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'less'
end
```

Then, run `bundle install` to get the `less` gem and its dependencies (which includes the `libv8` gem, by the way, and can take awhile to install).

Now it's just a matter of using the .css.less extension with the stylesheets in your `./app/assets/stylesheets` directory. Note that you won't get any helpful messages if you have any syntax errors in your LESS files (this tripped me up for a second).

Comment: make sure you include gem "commonjs"

Answer (score 18):

For Rails 3.1, we now have @metaskill's [less-rails](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) gem which provides helpers etc. specific to Rails. It is fairly new but seems to be actively maintained.

You can also use the [less-rails-bootstrap](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap) gem (by the same author) to pull in the bootstrap libraries.

```
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
```

Also see my post [here](http://opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/11/twitter-bootstrap-on-rails/) about using Bootstrap and its mixins on Rails.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straight, see [original doc here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets):

> Styling with LESS
>
> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins,
>   operations and functions.
>
> If the less gem is available to your application, you can use LESS to
>   write CSS assets in Sprockets. Note that the LESS compiler is written
>   in JavaScript, and at the time of this writing, the less gem depends
>   on therubyracer which embeds the V8 JavaScript runtime in Ruby.
>
> To write CSS assets with LESS, use the extension .css.less.