# How do I use the Bootstrap stylesheet from Twitter with my existing stylesheet in Rails without messing up everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I included the URL to the [stylesheet](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css) in my Rails app, but it throws everything into haywire.

I included it like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css', 'style', 'css3buttons', 'jquery.lightbox-0.5', :media => 'all') %>
```

What I want to do, is to just have the Twitter styles applied when I apply the class to the html tag. Ideally, what I would like to do is have it even override the styles in my 'style' sheet - which is the stylesheet for my entire app.

Is it possible to do this in an easy way, without having to modify the style for every single element I want to work with?

Answer (score 7):

Look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.css, you'll notice it defines resets  and styles on root html elements.

For example:

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
}
```

So, if your style.css already defines a style for `h1` or if your layout expects the `h1` to have a different margin, your layout is not going to look as expected.

Twitter bootstrap is generally for when you start a project and not something you can completely plug into an existing project's stylesheets without any problems.

An alternative is to use [their LESS stylesheets](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/lib) if you want to include, for example, just the forms and table styles. ([using Bootstrap with Less](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#less)).

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="lib/tables.less">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="lib/forms.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You're not going to want to use `lib/boostrap.less` since includes everything, but you can include the other LESS stylesheets that work for you. Be warned, just including a subset of the twitter boostrap, may not work as expected, especially if you don't have css resets defined. If that doesn't work for you, look into using [Preboot.less](http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/) instead. Note: [Rails 3.1 supports LESS compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341676/using-less-in-a-rails-3-1-app)

If you still want to use the complete twitter bootstrap css in your application, you can create a new rails layout template that uses the twitter bootstrap. Then, build your new pages with the twitter boostrap, specify `render :layout => "boostrap"` or something similar to have your new pages use the twitter bootstrap layout. Then, when you're ready, you can migrate your old pages to the new layout template.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out such a detailed response. What I am trying to do, ideally, is integrate the styles into my current layout. So, for instance, I have a header that is applied via my `application.html.erb` across all layouts. I would like to apply one or two of Bootstrap's styles there. That's just one example, but there are others for various layouts and various sections of the `master layout` of the app. The alternative is I could just copy the styles from Bootstrap to my stylesheet, but was trying to avoid that...if possible.

Comment: @marcamillion try the LESS example e.g. add the LESS stylesheets after your other stylesheets in your layout

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change order of css loading..

in your case  to override your app stylesheet with bootstrap

first load your app stylesheet and then bootstrap.css

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag :default %>
```

and then

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag  ('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css', :media => 'all') %>
```

Comment: The weirdest thing is, when I do this - i.e. load my main stylesheet first, then do the Bootstrap, it overrides more styles than when I load it BEFORE my main stylesheet.

Comment: Overridng behaviour is simply because of the style class name's clashes.
SO, Either your change names in main stylesheet OR
remove styling elements from bootstrap.css

Comment: I know...ideally though, what I would want to do is have my main stylesheet supersede everything else, except when there are no classes with that name in my main sheet. E.g. if my stylesheet has a class `alert-message`, then Twitter bootstrap won't clash it will just use mine (because I set mine as superseding). But if it doesn't have that class name, it will use Twitter's style because the Bootstrap.css DOES have that class name. Make sense?

Comment: I understand that I might not be able to do this right now...but if I wanted to approach this - as say write a gem for it - how would I go about approaching this?

Comment: I am assuming You need to override your main stylesheets's style with twitter ones ? right?
Try declaring the twitter style tag first followed by main apps stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Override my main with Twitter. That didn't work either, unfortunately :(

Comment: So it's just a name clash; All u can do is remove unwanted style definitions from bootstrap.css.It hardly will take a min.rest will be overridden as usual :)

Comment: Ahh....but the issue is that I use the hosted min.css file...not a locally hosted one :)

Comment: you can simply download it keep in stylesheets folder and modify and use it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply customize the bootstrap from twitter github customization tool [Customize Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)

Select only items of your choice and download customized version.

I was also in search of something like this since long , Now I did and helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use less or sass mixins for this purpose, boostrap provides some nice ones.

For instance :

```
<!- our new, semanticized HTML -->
<article>
  <section class="main">...</section>
  <aside></aside>
</article>

<!-- its accompanying Less stylesheet -->
article {
  .makeRow();

  section.main {
    .makeColumn(10);
  }

  aside {
    .makeColumn(2);
  }
}
```

See http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html for some more details, and http://www.sitepoint.com/5-useful-sass-mixins-bootstrap/ and also
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins