# using bootstrap based AngularJS libraries without breaking CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I have an AngularJS app in development, and the CSS is already done, just adding functionality.

What I now need is stuff like

- date pickers
- modals
- tooltips

I'd love to use some of the stuff from [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap), but it's based on the bootstrap.css file.

If I don't include the bootstrap file, it doesn't work. If I include it, it works, but it breaks *everything*, my whole layout is destroyed. That happens also if I include the bootstrap.css first.

I then tried to only load partial elements from the bootstrap site. For example, the date picker from angular-strap said to use elements like tooltip, so I only used the tooltip css elements using the bootstrap customiser, then it displays but inline, not a tooltip anymore.

It's quite frustrating. Is there a way to add those amazing libraries without breaking the CSS of the existing app? I'm somehow not seeing what's really required for that.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8892414/3116322 (summary: Bootstrap works well for greenfield projects, but it was not designed for ease of integration into existing projects)

Answer (score 1):

My company's project is in the exact same situation. We use Foundations for our grid layout. But we want to use things like AngularUI which is based off of foundations.

What we've done is to include the bootstrap JS. And then selectively choose the bootstrap css that is needed. Doing it this way has given us the ability to use Datepicker & Modal. (Although, recently I found some better angular datepickers - and the angularUI datepickers just don't have the usability that I was looking for).

So it seems that what you may be missing is the JS for bootstrap. But without seeing your code it's really hard to say.

Per your request, here are some of the datepickers that I like better:

- [ngQuickDate](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate)
- [ng-bs-daterangepicker](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-bs-daterangepicker) (useful for date ranges) (although, this one also has a BS dependency)
- [Jquery UI Datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/zx2pY/) (`implemented as a directive`)

Comment: It's not really related to the JS, because when I include the whole bootstrap.css it all the functionality of angular-strap is there. It just breaks the rest of the layout.

Comment: out of curiosity: what date pickers are you using now?

Comment: I"m not a bootstrap expert, but I was under the impression that the JS often altered the CSS/styling. It's an easy thing to test out though (if you haven't already). Just include the JS and see if it makes it look different.

Comment: Added some of the other datepickers that I like.

Comment: angular-strap is not based on bootstrap JS, so it doesn't have an effect