# Rails 4.0 - Need Background Image To Display on Landing Page with Different Format Than Application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, background-image

I submitted the question below a few months ago where I had a problem with a background image not working when I upgraded my Rails 3 application to Rails 4.  The solution was to use scss and precompile the production assets.

[Rails 4 - Background Image Appears in Localhost but not in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461256/rails-4-background-image-appears-in-localhost-but-not-in-production)

I have a slightly different problem that I need help with.  I have a landing page with a different format than the main website.  When I do this I normally code my CSS code in my layout page.  In my situation I would add style tags to landing.html.erb.  I want to set a background image for html and stretch it across the entire screen only for the landing page.  I have tried two things but cannot get this working.

I first tried adding the following code in landing.html.erb in the style tag:

```
html { 
  background: asset-url("SplashPage-Image.jpg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

I then tried to implement something similar to the solution on the previous question.

**application.css.scss**

```
@import 'landing';
```

**landing.css.scss**

```
html { 
  background: asset-url("SplashPage-Image.jpg"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

In both cases when I look at the source I can find the code when I look at the css files but the image does not show up.  I have tried `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and `rake assets:precompile`.  It makes no difference. I have found a good number of questions on Stack Overflow regarding background images but none of them  deal with my specific situation.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `background: url("SplashPage-Image.jpg"); no-repeat center center fixed;`?

Comment: No but I will now.  I will add it first to landing then try it in my layout file.

Comment: I put this code in landing.css.scss.  I do see the background image, just not where I want it.  Right now the background image shows up at the bottom of each page whereas I only want the background image to show on the landing page on the page itself, not under the page.  I need to figure out where to place the css code.  I will probably have to wrap my css code for the landing page in a class then do a background image within the class.  Thanks!!

Comment: I decided to move the code into my main stylesheet.  It worked there as well.  I changed center center fixed to top center fixed.  Working great!!!